# How to have facebook messenger bot in local, staging and production

Tags: facebook, workflow, platform, messenger

**Context**

I'm working on a facebook messenger bot and have a workflow issue.

To create it i used ngrok to make a facebook test application hook on my local and it worked fine.

Now the bot is in staging for test and an other application have the webhook pointing to the stage server.

For the production server i intend to do a production application that will have webhook pointing on it.

**Question**

But since an application has to be attached to a page to start a conversation to it, how can i test several bots ? 
Do i need 3 pages (local test, staging test and production) ?

Or is there a Facebook way to it ? (test version of app is not working for now on messenger bot, known bug)

Or maybe a good practice ?

Comment: I guess possible approach could be creating different fb applications linking to different fb pages and then linking apps to the respective servers

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Test Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/) in Facebook App Development. You can find this setting on the Developer Page on the top left where you can find a drop-down button to create a Test App.

I use to create my dev and staging environment.

Comment: You still need to create 3 separate pages to subscribe the different bots to though, right? Or how can one person talk to the dev bot, another to staging, another with prod through the same FB page?

Answer (score 1):

Docs on this seem non-existent. It does seem like you need separate pages and bots for test/staging environments.

Here's what I did for [the bot I made](https://www.messenger.com/t/doorstepsapp/).

1. Make test/staging pages.
2. Unpublish those pages so they're not publicly searchable.
3. Give testers/devs `Page Roles` on the page so they can search for and find it.
4. Give those same testers/devs roles in the bot dashboard so they can actually chat with the bot.